# control audio kde plasma after hdmi removal

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, kde, plasma

I am using kde:plasma version 4.13.3 in ubuntu 14.04 and it works great in most ways, but on my laptop I frequently use it as my "media center" pc.  I hook it up to the TV through the HDMI port.  When I do that everything works great.  The sound for Netflix, VLC, Desktop Sound, Hangouts, etc.... but after I disconnect the HDMI cable I can no longer hear sound from Netflix, YouTube, or any other browser based audio.  I tested this in Firefox and Google Chrome.

I am guessing this is controlled separately some how.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Install pavucontrol and use it to switch the audio output to internal speakers, after disconnecting the HDMI cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clicking the speeker icon (kmix) in the system tray ,,,,,,,you will see the firefox,chrome, audio streem volume slider ,,,,,,,,right click the icon at the top of the slider ,,,,,you will see a move to option ,,,,point at it and select the "analogue stereo"

VINNY

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you please clarify your answer? In its current form it is very hard to read.

Comment: Or perhaps a screen shot ;)

Comment: not allowed to post screenshots yet :(

Comment: not allowed to post screenshots yet :(     I have been using Kubuntu sense 2009 and what I posted are the exact steps to redirect the browser audio stream from the HDMI device to the analogue stereo device in the Quickest and easiest manor without putsing   around in system settings or installing an extra volume control IE:pavucontrole (pulse audio volume control)

Comment: screenshot @hear https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67857-sound-issues-after-removing-hdmi

Comment: for some reason those things aren't in kmix...any ideas why?

Comment: hard to say without knowing if you installed Kubuntu or how you added KDE to your Ubuntu ..........But if you started off with Ubuntu you should have :pavucontrole (pulse audio volume control) by default, use it to redirect the audio stream from the playback tab wile audio is playing in a browser .

Comment: i figured out what the issue was.  If you pause the video the steam stops and doesn't show up.  It works now.  Any idea why this doesn't change automatically?

Comment: @Goddard LOL yes if paused it will disappear,,,,,,,,,No not sure why it (HDMI)dose not release it automatically ! but glad you got it sorted out

Answer (score 1):

User68186 is right, the HDMI hogs the sound, this happens after upgrades too! Leftclick the small speaker in the upper right corner and chose "Sound Settings"
[image]
Go to Output devises and check, The sound is vissible as a voobling blue line, and its still attached to hdmi, click on internal speakers, it vill start playing from the speakers, eaven if you have to select it a couble of times.

Comment: what program is that?  I only have KMix in the system tray.